# Как расположить 2 inline-block друг под другом без костылей?

Tags: html, css, inline, blocks

Есть 2 `inline-block`, их нужно поместить друг под другом. Есть ли способ без костылей и не правя 'html' это сделать?
з.ы. в изначальном коде в инлайн блоках содержатся динамические элементы, поэтому нельзя применять ширину `100%`

```css
.a,
.b {
  display: inline-block;
}
.a,
.b {
  float: left;
}
.b {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">Текст</div>
<div class="b">Текст</div>
```

Comment: а зачем вы флоутите то, что заинлайнено? О_________________О

Comment: а разве заставлять inline блоки вести себя не так, как задумано изначально, это уже не костыли?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский "а зачем вы флоутите то, что заинлайнено?" есть у меня такая потребность - этого достаточно?
" потому что они к тегам прописаны, а не к классам" - поправил, быстро набирал - опечатался

Comment: @lexxl если уже так разобраться - любое `css` правило - это костыль, который вмешивается в изначальную структуру html

Comment: чёт я всё равно не понимаю, этот `css` с `float` в вопросе - это у вас в проекте так и изменять нельзя? или зачем он там?

Comment: @lexxl `css` менять можно, я про него ничего не говорил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас в принципе подход не правильный, вам нужно либо добавить врапперы, либо хотя бы `<br />` добавить.

**Добавить обертку:**

```css
.a,
.b {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="a">Текст</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="b">Текст</div>
</div>
```

**Добавить перенос:**

```css
.a,
.b {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">Текст</div>
<br /><div class="b">Текст</div>
```

**Либо через псевдоэлементы, но только для `display: inline;`:**

```css
.a,
.b {
  display: inline;
  white-space:pre; 
}
.b:before {
  content: '\00000A';
}
```

```html
<div class="a">Текст</div>
<div class="b">Текст</div>
```

Еще вариант через `white-space: pre;` для родителя, но тогда будут учитываться все проблемы и переносы в разметке:

```css
.parent {
  white-space: pre;
}
.a,
.b {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"><div class="a">Текст</div>
<div class="b">Текст</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант, который вижу я:

```css
.a,
.b {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">Текст</div>
<div class="b">Текст</div>
```

Comment: нет, вот как раз-таки с шириной нельзя играться: там в инлайн блоках динамические элементы наполняются-исчезают- в этом вся и проблема. упрощал код - не упомянул об этом

Comment: @Вася а вот надо упоминать как можно больше информации, чтоб не возникало таких сюрпризов)

Comment: дополнил описание

Comment: @Вася Мне кажется вам еще больше инфы надо добавить. Что у вас там добавляется, что вы делаете, для чего это нужно. Что НЕ нужно и т.д. А то так мало что понятно

Comment: `php` цикл добавить? а смысл